# Simulate Control-Alt-Delete key sequence in Vista and XP

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-vista

Can I simulate in C#/C++ code <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> sequence in Vista? 
When UAC enabled/disabled?
How it is done in XP?

Can you provide a code sample that works in Vista?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existing code to simulate the Secure Attention Sequence (SAS), which most people refer to as control alt delete or ctrl-alt-del, no longer works in Windows Vista. It seems that Microsoft offers a library that exports a function called SimulateSAS(). It is not public and one is supposed to request it by sending a mail to saslib@microsoft.com.

There is a [similar library](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2009/03/30/sending-ctrl-alt-del-simulate-sas-in-windows-vista/) available with the following features:

- Works both with and without
  User Account Control (UAC)
- Supports current, console and
  any Terminal Server session
- Does not need a driver
- The calling application does not need
  to be signed or have a special
  manifest
- Supports multiple programming
  languages

Please note that this library is not free. Meanwhile you can contact [info@simulatesas.com](http://mailto:info@simulatesas.com) if you are interested in it.

Comment: Thank for linking to my SasLibEx which indeed supports simulating SAS and lot's more!

Answer (score 2):

Please use below information, "saslib@microsoft.com" is deprecated and less likely to get any responses. Below information is sufficient.

Beginning with the public availability of the Windows 7 Operating System and accompanying Software Development Kit (SDK), SAS functionality for Vista applications will only be available through the Windows SDK. The release support through email of the SASLIB package, and the saslib will be discontinued.

Information on how to download the platform SDK can be found on the Microsoft Download Center page for the “Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .Net Framework 3.5 SP1” at the following link:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en.

After you install this SDK you will find the redistributable sas.dll in the redist directory:

\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\redist\x86\sas.dll

\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\redist\amd64\sas.dll

\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\redist\ia64\sas.dll

Comment: Note: On Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2, the SASLIB package is not necessary and should not be used. Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 have built-in SAS functionality callable via the SendSAS function. SendSAS is documented on MSDN at the following location: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979761(VS.85).aspx.
You may also want to review following documentation as it might provide the functionality you desire in place of SASLIB:
• Create Custom Login Experiences With Credential Providers For Windows Vista: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had bookmarked this URL, hope it help.
http://softltd.wordpress.com/simulate-ctrl-alt-del-in-windows-vista-7-and-server-2008/

Answer (score 0):

PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_HOTKEY, 0, MAKELONG(MOD_ALT | MOD_CONTROL, VK_DELETE));

You get PostMessage from the user32 dll

edit: [CodeProject article that has code for it](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/alt_control_delete.aspx?fid=14112&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2634100&fr=26)

edit: There is some [discussion from VNC](http://www.uvnc.com/vista/) on why that won't work in Vista and how to set up UAC to allow it.

Comment: before I mod you up :), the article does not mention vista. does it work with vista?

Comment: No -- Look at the article on VNC for the caveats for sending CTRL-ALT-DEL to Vista with UAC enabled.  You cannot do that, it seems.  There are ways to bring up the Task Manager if that's what you are aiming to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call next code from service process only

```
HDESK desktop = OpenDesktopW(L"Winlogon", 0, TRUE,
    DESKTOP_CREATEMENU | DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW | DESKTOP_ENUMERATE | 
    DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL | DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS | DESKTOP_READOBJECTS |
    DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP | GENERIC_WRITE);
int result = SetThreadDesktop(desktop);
if (result)
{
    HMODULE sasdll = LoadLibraryA("sas.dll");
    if (sasdll)
    {
        typedef void(__stdcall * SendSAS_t)(BOOL);
        SendSAS_t sendSAS = (SendSAS_t)GetProcAddress(sasdll, "SendSAS");
        if (sendSAS)
            sendSAS(FALSE);
    }
}
CloseDesktop(desktop);
```

Comment: Also you have to set a registry key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\SoftwareSASGeneration** to 1 or 3. [You can see information here](https://getadmx.com/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.WindowsLogon2::SoftwareSASGeneration)